# Can't see changes in blade Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I recently started learning Laravel 5.4 and so far so good,but I have a problem with displaying the newest data in my .blade files-it's like Laravel has some sort of stupid caching

**NOTE:** I'm using shared hosting and can't use console on server for php artisan(but I could run them in the code)

In routes I'm calling controller like this

```
Route::get('/home', 'PostController@get');
```

**PostController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Validator;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class PostController extends Controller
{

/**
 * Home page
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function get(Request $request)
   {



        //$artisan = Artisan::call('view:clear'); -->failed attempt of clearing

       $posts = DB::table('posts')
       ->leftJoin('users','posts.id_user_post','=','users.id_user')
       ->orderBy('id_post','desc')
       ->get();

      if($request->session()->has('id'))
         {
            $options = DB::table('users')
            ->select('avatar_url_user','cookies_user','settings_user')
            ->where('id_user','=',$request->session()->get('id'))
            ->get();

            return view('home',['posts' => $posts,'options' => $options]);
         }



       //$posts = DB::table('posts')->leftJoin('users','posts.id_user_post','=','users.id_user')->orderBy('id_post','desc')->get();
       // $user =  DB::table('users')->where()
       return view('home',['posts' => $posts,'options'=>0]);

   }
```

}

**home.blade.php**

```
...
{{ $options }}
...
```

and if I change  it to {{ "something" }} it will display "something" and if I change it to $options then it will still remain "something"

I googled for a solution and I did found some questions here on Stack Overflow but none of them solved my problem(or are outdated)

So if somebody could explain to me how to solve this problem step by step that would be great

Comment: Try CTRL + f5 and see if the data changed. I had the same problem with the CSS modifications and this works for me

Comment: Not working for me unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

your if-statement needs a "else". whats happening now is, it doesn't matter if the condition is true or not your still going to the same view (which is the last one). but that's just one of the errors I think. if you are using ->get(), you need to say foreach($options as $option) ... @endforeach, in the view. if you are expecting just one row (or model as laravel puts it) you can say ->first().

good luck

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using foreach

Comment: Can you add also the complete code? with the foreach loop